# Finding an object with equal member values

Tags: c++, vector, member

So I have a `Card` class with `_suit` and `_rank` members:

```
class Card {    
private:
    char _suit;
    int _rank;
public:
    Card(char, int);     //Constructor

    char suit() const;   //Returns the _suit value

    int rank() const;    //Returns the _rank value
}
```

I also have a vector `vector<Card> Deck`. What I would like to check is whether `Deck` has `Card`s that have the same `_rank` value. I have tried using `std::adjecent_find` but that only works for primitive data types(?). Of course a nested for loop could be used, but is there a more efficient alternative?

Comment: Are you aware of operator overloading [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) [2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)?

Comment: "*I have tried using `std::adjecent_find` but that only works for primitive data types(?)*" - actually, it is overloaded to let you specify a custom predicate for comparing elements.

Comment: Is it your intention to find only consecutive equivalent values, or are you trying to find _any_ that satisfy your criteria? `std::adjacent_find` is used to find two consecutive elements that compare equal (or whose `BinaryPredicate` returns `true`).

Answer (score 1):

Any of the algorithms of this nature can usually have a *predicate* which basically means a function that tells the algorithm what you are looking for. For example, [std::find_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) takes a `UnaryPredicate`:

```
template< class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate >
InputIt find_if( InputIt first, InputIt last,
                 UnaryPredicate p );
```

which we could overload to suit your needs with a lambda, for eg:

```
auto predicate = [myCard](const Card& card) { 
    return myCard.rank() == card.rank();
}
```

You can apply something similar to `adjacent_find` but i will let you do this as an excersize.

Comment: In this case, `std::adjacent_find()` have overloads that accept a `BinaryPredicate` to compare 2 elements.